# How to parse a string containing spaces in C++?

Tags: c++, string

I have a string like this:

```
aaa bbb
```

There is a space before the 2nd part of the string.
My goal is to parse only the first part, so `aaa`.
Everything after the space is out.
How can I do this in C++?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I tokenize a string in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/53849/how-do-i-tokenize-a-string-in-c)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: **wrong dup / do not close** He wants the first part, not all. General tokeniziation is an unnecessary performance waste here.

Comment: @phresnel I agree, but while this seems like exactly the sort of thing that's constantly asked, I couldn't find a better duplicate.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: If you couldn't, then it isn't, imho.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
std::string s = "aaa bbb";
std::string s_before_space = s.substr(0, s.find(' '));
```

Comment: This is the best solution.
Smart, fast, clear and very useful.
Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

```
std::string s = "aaa bbb";

s = s.substr(0, s.find_first_of(' '));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 std::string s = "aaa bbb";
 std::istringstream ss(s);

 std::string token;
 if (ss>>token)   // or: while(ss>>token) for _all_ tokens
 { 
      std::cout << "first token only: " << token << std::endl;
 }
```

Alternatively, with a container and using `<algorithm>`

```
 std::string s = "aaa bbb";
 std::istringstream ss(s);

 std::vector<std::string> elements;
 std::copy(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(ss),
           std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
           std::back_inserter(elements));

 // elements now contains the whitespace delimited tokens
```

Includes:

```
 #include <sstream>   // for ostringstream/istringstream/stringstream
 #include <algorithm> // for copy
 #include <iterator>  // for istream_iterator/back_inserter
```

Comment: But he only wants the first part, not all. General tokenization here = waste of performance.

Comment: I tried the second method of yours; the vector is empty after `std::copy` call.

Comment: @phresnel: then just make it `if (ss>>token) { ... }`? I'd prefer str.substr(0, str.find_first_of(" \t"))` though

Comment: @sehe: Like the first part better now :)

Comment: @jrok: oops, blatant typo - fixed now. Thanks for reporting!

Answer (score -1):

user following tokenizer, taken from some earlier post on this site.

```
void Tokenize(const std::string& str, std::vector<std::string>& tokens,const std::string& delimiters = " ") {
    std::string::size_type lastPos = str.find_first_not_of(delimiters, 0);
    std::string::size_type pos     = str.find_first_of(delimiters, lastPos);
    while (std::string::npos != pos || std::string::npos != lastPos){
        tokens.push_back(str.substr(lastPos, pos - lastPos));
        lastPos = str.find_first_not_of(delimiters, pos);
        pos = str.find_first_of(delimiters, lastPos);
    }
}
```

Comment: But he only wants the first part, not all. General tokenization here = waste of performance. -1 because you just pasted without explanation.